# Make a link for an address that opens the default map app

Tags: html, anchor

HTML provides for:

- `<a href="tel:+5558675309">555-867-5309</a>` for a link to dial a phone number
- `<a href="mailto:alice@example.com">alice@example.com</a>` to trigger drafting an email message.

Is there some such provision for make a link of an address that loads the street address into the computer’s default map app? Even better would be a link for a business’ identity along with that street address.

I know I can embed a URL to a specific mapping vendor web site such as *Google Maps* or *Bing Maps*. But I would prefer to activate the user’s default map app.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing is the [GEO URI scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5870). It can link to map coordinates (latitude and longitude) like:

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677">
```

Stack exchange doesn't let me create a GEO link here for you to test. You can go to the [Wikipedia page for GEO URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) to get a clickable example.

There are some severe limitations:

- It doesn't support street addresses.  The specification states:

  > The provision of more complex geometries or locations described by civic
  > addresses is out of scope of this document.

  The scheme does support a map search and addresses often work as the query parameter like `<a href="geo:0,0?q=123+main+st,+anytown+XX">`
- Support for it is spotty. Newer Android and iPhones have some support for it, but desktop browsers generally don't. There are JavaScript libraries like [dojo-geo-uri-polyfill](https://github.com/prowestgis/dojo-geo-uri-polyfill) that use some specific map provider to open such links.